# Cannot GET /uploads/images/ in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

I just uploaded and read data from mongodb but now when I try to open / read that image from path it says Cannot GET /uploads/images/ I already app.use(express.static('uploads')); my directory looks like

```
|app.js
  |uploads
    |images
```

code of receving and displaying image

```
route.get('/uploads/images/:filename',(req,res) => {
res.sendFile(__dirname,"../uploads/"+req.param('filename'));
});
```

here is html

```
<% file.forEach(function(files){ %>
<img src="<%= files.file_thumbnail %>" alt="">
<p><%= files.caption %></p>
```

and db returns path of image is ./uploads/images/me-01.jpg
what should I do now ?

Answer (score 4):

The bellow worked for me:

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/front/index.html'));
});
```

?

Comment: Adapt part after __dirname for your purposes :)

Answer (score 0):

I had such error to about 24 hours but, the following codes worked for me:

`app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));`

Where uploads is your public directory name, and in my example it is on the same level with my `server.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there is no such route as uploads.

You can either implement uploads route and search if you have such image then return it. Or you can make the uploads folder publicly available like this.

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
```

Answer (score 0):

- try to use "path"

  ```
   app.use('/uploads/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads/images')))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

try use this:

```
app.get('/uploads/:filename', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/uploads/' + req.params.filename));
});
```

[problem solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkq62.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. To be safe you should append the absolute path of the directory you want to serve. You should try

```
app.use('/uploads/images', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads/images'))
```